# Multiple matches from column 2 and combine with column 1 separately from terminal

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed

I have a file which has content as follows in 2 columns

```
fsfsfsf ukd18178486|ukd18178488  
adadvafv ukd17647236|ukd17647238  
bcghdbdhdb ukd18256238|ukd18256240|ukd18256242|ukd18256243|ukd18256244  
dadadad ukd18318607|ukd18318608|ukd18318609
```

What I need to do is generate a separate file with patterns like

```
fsfsfsf?ukd=ukd18178486  
fsfsfsf?ukd=ukd18178488  
adadvafv?ukd=ukd17647236  
adadvafv?ukd=ukd17647238  
bcghdbdhdb?ukd=ukd18256238  
bcghdbdhdb?ukd=ukd18256240  
bcghdbdhdb?ukd=ukd18256242
```

Basically combine every row in first column with all corresponding 'ukd[0-9]+' in the 2nd column and so on till all the rows in the first column are exhausted. Any approaches using any combination of awk/grep/sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{n=split($2,a,"|"); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s?udk=%s\n",$1,a[i]}' file

fsfsfsf?udk=ukd18178486
fsfsfsf?udk=ukd18178488
adadvafv?udk=ukd17647236
adadvafv?udk=ukd17647238
bcghdbdhdb?udk=ukd18256238
bcghdbdhdb?udk=ukd18256240
bcghdbdhdb?udk=ukd18256242
bcghdbdhdb?udk=ukd18256243
bcghdbdhdb?udk=ukd18256244
dadadad?udk=ukd18318607
dadadad?udk=ukd18318608
dadadad?udk=ukd18318609
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^((.* )[^|]*)\|/\1\n\2/;s/ ([^0-9]*)/?\1=\1/;P;D' file
```

Replace the `|` by a newline and the key of the record. Then pattern match on the record to transform the record to the required format. Print the first line, delete the first line and repeat.

This most likely could be achieved with one substitution but if the second substitution is removed the observer can see how the first substitution transforms the line from one to two etc.